# Count from two array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array, arrLevel1 and arrLevel2.
I want to count animal that can walk.
How can I do that array stucture like this?
Thx before. I already tried, but it failed.
arrLevel1:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Walk"]=>
    string(4) "Bird"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Walk"]=>
    string(3) "Cat"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Fly"]=>
    string(9) "ButterFLy"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Fly"]=>
    string(4) "Bird"
  }
}
```

arrLevel2:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Animal"]=>
    string(3) "Fly"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Animal"]=>
    string(11) "Walk"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Human"]=>
    string(11) "Walk"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you tried, and explain what it did or didn't do that makes it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$array = array(array('Walk' => 'Bird'), array('Walk' => 'Cat'), array('Fly' => 'ButterFly'), array('Fly' => 'Bird'));

$count = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    return key($item) == 'Walk' ? $carry + 1 : $carry;
}, 0);

var_dump($count);
```

You can use a similar code for the second version:

```
$array = array(array('Animal' => 'Fly'), array('Animal' => 'Walk'), array('Human' => 'Walk'));

$count = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    return reset($item) == 'Walk' ? $carry + 1 : $carry;
}, 0);

var_dump($count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check them in a loop
For the first arrLevel1:

```
<?php
$arrLevel1 = array(array("walk"=>"Bird"),array("walk"=>"Cat"),array("Fly"=>"Butterfly"),array("Fly"=>"Bird"));
$x = 0;
foreach($arrLevel1 as $p){

if($p["walk"]!==null){
$x++;
}

}
var_dump($x);
?>
```

Hope thsi helps you